# In Gnome Shell how can I remove activities button keeping the hot corner behaviour?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell. I want to remove the activities button, But keeping the top left hot corner behavior.

There are a couple shell extensions that do just the opposite, But I can't find out how to do what I want. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this new extension you can do it, and there is many other options.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/

Grettings!

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/292/remove-activities-button/

Comment: I tried, but as the third and fourth comment say :U.N.Bekannt
It should be stated, that this extension also removes the Hot Corner.

29 days ago

vanlong441
@U.N. you can remove only the hot corner and leave alone the Activities button but not the vice versa

29 days ago

Answer (score 1):

If you install this https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/327/axe-menu/ there's a possibility in its options to hide the activities button.

Comment: Well, that's an unexpected solution, but it works indeed. By the way, nice extension!